# Setting proper permissions for laravel logs

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, file-permissions

I cannot figure out how to set up proper permissions for my `storage/logs` folder.

I am trying to run an artisan command in the console and I am getting an error saying `The stream or file "/var/www/html/laravel-project/storage/logs/laravel-2019-05-04.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Current permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data   4096 May  3 02:45 storage
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 May  4 09:44 logs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  294932 May  4 19:58 laravel-2019-05-04.log
```

At first I set my permissions like 
1)

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data root/of/laravel/project
```

2) Added my user `Ubuntu` to the `www-data` group

`sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu`

3) Set all files to `644`

`sudo find /root/of/laravel/project -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

4) Set all directories to `755`

`sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

If I would run commands like in the console that caused an error I would get an error saying I did not have permissions to write to the log

So I tried it this way

1) Change owner of all directories to myself

`sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /root/of/laravel/project`

2) Give myself and the server permissions

```
sudo find /root/of/laravel/project -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;    
sudo find /root/of/laravel/project -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

3) Give the webserver read & write permissions for storage and cache folders

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

What is the proper way to set permissions properly so that I my user can write to the storage folder AND the web server can as well?

Comment: I had the same problem on Fedora. I changed the owner to `apache:apache` and now it works without error. Try and find the user name and group of your server (apache, httpd, ...)